# Why are injective $\mathscr{O}$-modules flasque?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, intuition, homology-cohomology, topos-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $\mathscr{O}$ be a sheaf of rings on $X$. It is easy to verify that the functor $\Gamma (U, -) : \textbf{Mod}(\mathscr{O}) \to \textbf{Ab}$ is representable, and that the representation is moreover natural in $U$. An easy argument [Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, Ch. III, Lem. 2.4] then shows that any injective $\mathscr{O}$-module is flasque in the sense of Godement, hence acyclic for $\Gamma(X, -) : \textbf{Ab}(\textbf{Sh}(X)) \to \textbf{Ab}$ (note the change of category!).

This seems to be a bizarre proof, and not easily generalised to an arbitrary (Grothendieck) topos $\mathcal{E}$. Yet it is true: this is part of what [Lemma `03FD`](http://www.math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/locate.php?tag=03FD) in [Stacks] asserts. An even stronger result is true: for *all* objects $E$ in $\mathcal{E}$, any injective $\mathscr{O}$-module is acyclic for $\mathcal{E}(E, -) : \textbf{Ab}(\mathcal{E}) \to \textbf{Ab}$, i.e. flasque in the sense of Verdier. This is [Lemma `072Z`](http://www.math.columbia.edu/algebraic_geometry/stacks-git/locate.php?tag=072Z) in [Stacks]. The proofs, however, go via Čech cohomology, and seem less straightforward than the proof in the special case outlined in the previous paragraph.

**Question 1.** What is the intuitive meaning of flasqueness in the sense of Verdier? Can it be characterised as a property of sheaves of sets?

**Question 2.** What is the moral reason for the flasqueness of injective $\mathscr{O}$-modules?

Comment: Linked up the tags from the Stacks project. Hope I got it right.

Comment: @Dylan: Thanks! I got one of the citations wrong, but I've replaced it with the right one now.